# Why is the text so blurry?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

It looks like all of the text everywhere is fuzzy and hard to read. Like it's in a font that isn't aliased or I don't have installed on my computer. The text in the launcher and all the other graphics look fine.

Comment: What kind of monitor are you using?  Most have native resolutions that display much better, and could be causing this.

Comment: It's an old CRT whose highest resolution is 1280x1024. But I prefer a lower resolution because I don't know how to make the Windows interface large enough to see on higher resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase your resolution from 1024x768 to 1280x960. That worked for me.

Comment: why is this so heavily downvoted?

Comment: This actually was the solution to my problem, I posted the question and answer as a public service because it was not on Google. So the downvote is ill-founded.

Comment: @Robotnik One would assume because *that's how "resolution" works*.

Comment: If resolution worked by making all the text blurry, I would have stopped running at 1024x768 years ago. It's just this game.